# SQL Server 2005 lags considerably 20% into a 250,000,000 row import

Tags: sql-server-2005

We have a 130 Gb database with 55 Gb of free space that we can't seem to reclaim. The data is mostly archival in nature, so we're not really sure where the extra space seems to have come from.

I had the idea to recreate the database by running a flat export from the original to the new copy, with the premise that the new database wouldn't have phantom dead place up in it all over the place.

To make sure logging wasn't an issue, I set the new DB to simple, and set up an export job from the original db, which ran as expected until it got to about 40,000,000 rows (out of 200,000,000) in... at which point it just slowed to a crawl.

What kinds of things should I be looking for to train and improve throughput throughout the length of the export?

Attached is a screen shot of fields and indexes on the table.

[image: fields and indexes]

Comment: Why do you think simple = no logging? Did you check to see if this was an outgrow event on either the data or the log file? If on the data file, did you check to see if instant file initialization is enabled?

Comment: Post the execution plan of the slowest query. Sudden slowdown with increasing data size usually means that working set has exhausted RAM. This forces access to disk which is >100x slower. Drop off a cliff. Drop all indexes. I suspect they cause random page access, in turn causing big working set.

Comment: I have to be honest. I just spent five minutes staring at Aaron's first question. Dumbfounded not at it, but at my reply. Because I don't have a why. I just... uh... always thought that's what simple meant. The bluntness of the question betrays my utter ignorance at what should have been a no-brainer. 

I will back slowly into a corner, cry for a while, and then be back with answers to these and usr's questions on Monday. 

Usr, I am thinking it might be indexes too. Wondering if dropping them first, then rebuilding after the move might be a better idea.

Comment: @DaveClary this is pretty much always a better idea if you are rewriting an entire table.

Comment: Btw, how did you try to reclaim the space?